# Apple TV YouTube Error

Tags: appletv

I have an Apple TV 4th gen, and whenever I try watching YouTube it says, "An error occurred loading this content. Try again later."

I've unplugged and plugged back in the wire, yet it still doesn't work. I also made it reboot. Every thing else is working though (Netflix, movie trailers, etc).

Anything would be helpful, thanks.

Comment: What model of Apple TV is it?

Comment: My Apple TV is the 4th generation and it has the same issue since yesterday.